# Can I use jQuery Mobile's page transitions on content blocks in one page?

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-mobile

jQuery Mobile has page transitions built in to the framework that's used to switch between "pages". Can I use the same behavior to transition between blocks of content inside of one page?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. As long as those blocks are in page divs

Comment: Thank you.  Do you have an example you can cite?  I'm also looking into implementing this behavior.  I should add that I wish to simulate the transition animation, as well.

Comment: Any reason why this was downvoted? Has jQuery Mobile changed in this respect since then? If so, maybe the downvoter would like to provide an updated answer?